# Bootstrap 4 Card Image Resizing on Mobile

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm working on a responsive web app in Bootstrap 4 and use cards with images on one of the pages.  Everything works fine through any window resizing on a desktop view; however, when I view them on mobile the card image height is completely off and about half the size of what it should be.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="container">
 <header class="jumbotron">
     <div class="container">
         <h1>By The Numbers.</h1>
         <p>View our growing database:</p>
         <p>
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large" href="/players/new">Add New Player</a>
         </p>
         <p>
             <form action="/players" method="GET" class="form-inline">
                 <div class="form-group">
                     <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Player Search..." class="form-control">
                     <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default">
                 </div>
             </form>
         </p>
     </div>
 </header>
<div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 mb-4">
            <div class="card">
                <img src="https://t3.ftcdn.net/jpg/02/12/43/28/240_F_212432820_Zf6CaVMwOXFIylDOEDqNqzURaYa7CHHc.jpg" id="playerCardImage" class="card-img-top" alt="Name">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Name</h5>
                    <h5 class="card-title">Detail</h5>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">More Info</a>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
</div>
```

The below CSS was added to ensure the cards all remain the same height, but this seems to cause the issue where the image is extremely small on mobile.

CSS:

```
#playerCardImage {
width: 100%;
height: 15vh;
object-fit: cover;
}
```

A codepen with the card example can be found here: https://codepen.io/franchise/pen/MWaoXOp.

Detail:

- Cannot replicate sizing issue with Chrome Dev Tools mobile view, it only shows what I would *expect* the card to look like on mobile
- To recreate the issue, view the Codepen on mobile to see the image is about half of the size compared to viewing the Codepen on a desktop

What am I missing here?  Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a style based on id, can try to create the style based on class card-img-top.

```css
.card-img-top {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Footer Pen</title>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/main.css">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/175e0bfa97.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
     <header class="jumbotron">
         <div class="container">
             <h1>By The Numbers.</h1>
             <p>View our growing database:</p>
             <p>
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large" href="/players/new">Add New Player</a>
             </p>
             <p>
                 <form action="/players" method="GET" class="form-inline">
                     <div class="form-group">
                         <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Player Search..." class="form-control">
                         <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default">
                     </div>
                 </form>
             </p>
         </div>
     </header>
    <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 mb-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="https://t3.ftcdn.net/jpg/02/12/43/28/240_F_212432820_Zf6CaVMwOXFIylDOEDqNqzURaYa7CHHc.jpg" id="playerCardImage" class="card-img-top" alt="Name">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Name</h5>
                        <h5 class="card-title">Detail</h5>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">More Info</a>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
    </div>
</div>

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61617160/bootstrap-4-card-image-resizing-on-mobile#
         <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  Switching the CSS class eliminates a superfluous ID and the fixed height in pixels resolves the view issue in mobile.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You should use height in **percent**

```css
#playerCardImage {
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }


 @media all and (max-width:768px){
  #playerCardImage {
    width: 100%;
    height: 110px;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Footer Pen</title>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/main.css">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/175e0bfa97.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
     <header class="jumbotron">
         <div class="container">
             <h1>By The Numbers.</h1>
             <p>View our growing database:</p>
             <p>
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large" href="/players/new">Add New Player</a>
             </p>
             <p>
                 <form action="/players" method="GET" class="form-inline">
                     <div class="form-group">
                         <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Player Search..." class="form-control">
                         <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default">
                     </div>
                 </form>
             </p>
         </div>
     </header>
    <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 mb-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="https://t3.ftcdn.net/jpg/02/12/43/28/240_F_212432820_Zf6CaVMwOXFIylDOEDqNqzURaYa7CHHc.jpg" id="playerCardImage" class="card-img-top" alt="Name">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Name</h5>
                        <h5 class="card-title">Detail</h5>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">More Info</a>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
    </div>
</div>


         <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  This does resolve the sizing issue; however, if you have multiple cards with mulitple image sizes, the cards become different heights themselves.  I'm trying to maintain a consistent card height.

Comment: Use @media queries for mobile view.